# pandas unstack on reshaping the dataframe.

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this sample dataframe

```
ID1,ID2,info,Value
1,50,BA,101
1,50,BA,102
2,100,CA,03
2,100,CA,07
2,100,BA,09
2,100,BA,10
```

To reshape the data, I am using unstack and this is more like 90% which I want and it works.

```
grouped = df.groupby(['ID1','ID1','ID2','info'])[['Value']].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x.values, columns=[['Value']]))\
                        .unstack().sort_index(level=1, axis=1).reset_index(drop= True, level=1).reset_index()

grouped.columns = ['{}{}'.format(a,b) for a, b in df_grouped.columns]
```

and this is the result I have

```
ID1,ID2,info,Value0,Value1
1,50,BA,101,102
2,100,BA,9,10
2,100,CA,3,7
```

probably it would be more clearer if I can put all the ID1 in one row and if I have two different info value corresponding to the ID1, then I would like to achieve something similar like this

```
ID1,ID2,info,Value0,Value1,Value2,Value3
1,50,BA,101,102,,
2,100,[BA,CA],9,10,3,7
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should be changed by aggregate `list` first, then if necessary only unique values of list convert values to sets and back to lists and from another columns create DataFrame which is[`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html)ed to back:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['ID1','ID1','ID2']).agg(list)

grouped['info'] = grouped['info'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(grouped.pop('Value').values.tolist(),
                   index=grouped.index).add_prefix('Value')
grouped = grouped.join(df1)
print (grouped)
                 info  Value0  Value1  Value2  Value3
ID1 ID1 ID2                                          
1   1   50       [BA]     101     102     NaN     NaN
2   2   100  [BA, CA]       3       7     9.0    10.0
```